# AWS Cloudfront custom sub domain TSL / SSL: "Not secure / certificate invalid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking for some advice as how to most cost efficiently setup SSL for a subdomain e.g `https://images.example.com`.

Images are hosted in AWS S3 and I have a cloudfront distribution pointing to that bucket.

I have purchased a [single domain SSL cert from Comodo](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl.aspx) and successfully added it to my cloudfront distribution. That part was easy as pie.

However, when loading images on the subdomain I get a "Not secure / certificate invalid" in the browser bar.

Is this because I require a [wildcard SSL cert](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-wildcard.aspx)?

I have not tested that the SSL cert works on the main domain. Reason being there is currently a production site that I don't want to interfere with.

Before I rush out and purchase a much more expensive wildcard SSL cert, I want to make sure it is required.

I have a single subdomain for image hosting. I don't expect to ever ad more subdomains. What if I just purchase two single domain certs?

What are my options?

Comment: You can get certificates that contain a list of the subdomains that you need to support. They are usually cheaper than a wildcard cert. But you need to be careful to include all the domain names you need in the cert. You can't go back and add one later. Just take a look at the subject alt name extension of the stackoverflow cert for this website (but ignore the wildcarded names because you don't want to pay for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ACM (https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/ ) to issue an AWS issued wildcard certificate for your domain and use that instead?

As to why your existing cert won't work - does it have the domain in the cert (eg images.domain.com) as either the primary domain or as a SAN? If not, it won't work.

If you don't want to use a wildcard, you can use an ACM cert (or a cert you purchase from somewhere else) and issue it for the domain subdomain only? You don't have to use a wildcard but from a cost point of view if you are purchasing them, its often more cost-effective (although there are of course security concerns to consider). If you are using ACM, the certs are free - either domain specific or wildcard.

Comment: The existing cert only has the main domain - not the subdomain. So wildcard SSL cert is the only option?

Comment: @ChrisRich you will need a wildcard, or you can just make separate CloudFront distributions with individual certificates, which is probably what you should be doing, anyway.

Comment: Or you can create your SSL certificates with the correct names (example.com, images.example.com, www.example.com). However, Michael's comments about separate distributions with separate certificates using AWS Certificate Manager is the best solution. Plus they are free.